# Separate dataframe by certain value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have:

```
Out[94]:
customer_id bad
0   1   0
1   4   1
2   3   0
3   2   NaN
4   7   NaN
```

I want to make a new dataframe `first`, which consists of all rows with `bad == NaN` and `Second` which consists of others.

1. We need to find the first instance of `NaN`. I could do it more gentle:

```
for index, value in enumerate(target.bad):
    if np.isnan(value):
        break
```

2. We need to reassign new dataframes(I tried this, but failed):

`First = target.irow([1:index])`

I've been coding python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but couldn't you just use:

```
first = df[df['bad'].isnull()]
second = df[~df['bad'].isnull()]
```

Comment: When i tried this, it didnt work for some reason. Ehh

Comment: whats result of :  df.dtypes

Comment: Its okay, this is just me,sir